# embed json file within d3.js

Tags: json, d3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 am using this

instead of `d3.json("/d/4063550/flare.json", function(error, flare) {`

how do i make it use the json file within the html, like say i have

```
var jsonData = [{
 "name": "A",
 "children": [  
  {"name": "A1", "children": [{"name": "A12"},{"name": "A13"},{"name": "A14"}]  },
  {"name": "A2",    "children": [{"name": "A22"},{"name": "A23"},{"name": "A24"}]  }
 ]
}];
```

and i want to use this instead of an external json file, how do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**:

1.you can  assign the JSON data to variable name then You can build the tree layout

2.use one function to get the `JSON` data

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/r7xRy/2/) for 1 solution

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/xGKfu/)** for 2 solution

```
    var root = getData(),
    nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
    links = cluster.links(nodes);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, am not well versed with js.

 d3.json("mydata.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;
 
  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }
 
  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
 });

i see that the file is called here, and the function update elsewhere too . how do i update this piece of code with a json array.

Comment: basically can you make the changes in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 ? i want to use the var i declared instead of the json file. thanks man

Comment: perfect, understood how you made use of the collapse function now. thanks a ton bro, works like a charm !!

Comment: what is the use of size in that data structure? for visualization is it used anywhere?

Comment: It's a while down the line, but I just found this one useful - making d3 documents with user specific data means inlining the JSON is actually one of the better approaches.